# Rendering maps in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, maps

Is it possible to see a map in adobe illustrator with zoom rendering? What I want to do is use google maps or OSM or any other map as a reference background for a map I am trying to create in illustrator.

I have found vector maps from openvectormaps.com, but these are still vector images-the only difference between a raster image and this is it doesn't get pixelated.. I want to render maps as they zoom, like we can do in GIS software.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/243588/115

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you want to automatically have different amounts of detail for different zoom levels then no, you can't create that using Illustrator alone.

You could create several different maps with the required different levels of detail in Illustrator, but you would need additional code to switch between them based on the zoom.